# Including template footer.tpl.php within another template page.tpl.php

Tags: theming

I am looking for simple way to include footer.tpl.php that is just html block into another template like page.tpl.php. In Grails/Groovy that is as simple as

```
<g:render template="side_menu"/>
```

Is there a same simple way(preferred no use any panels, custom modules, etc) in Drupal? Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to include another .tpl.php file is the [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) function.

Another idea is to add your footer as a region in the [page.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!page.tpl.php/7) and assign a region wise theme as defined in [Drupal 7 Template (Theme Hook) Suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089656)

> **region--[region].tpl.php** 
>   The region template is used when a page region has content, either from the Block
>   system or a function like hook_page_build(). Possible region names are determined by the  > theme's .info file.

Comment: Thank you Nikhil. Per your suggestions, i created region such as 'footer', put the block code into block--footer.tpl.php file. Afterwards, rendered it within any template by "print render($page['footer'])"

Comment: Well..there is a problem with "render($page['footer'])". Drupal only calls for 'block--footer.tpl.php' region template if there is a block assigned to this region from the admin portal.

Comment: I end up using include as follows: <?php include './'. path_to_theme() .'/templates/block--footer.tpl.php';?>

Answer (score 2):

If your drupal site do not call for **region--[region].tpl.php** file, then check your template.php file and find preprocess_region function:

```
/**
 * Override or insert variables into the region templates.
 *
 * @param $variables
 *   An array of variables to pass to the theme template.
 * @param $hook
 *   The name of the template being rendered ("region" in this case.)
 */

function YOURTHEME_preprocess_region(&$variables, $hook) {
  // add theme suggestions for blockgroup region
  if (strpos($variables['region'],'blockgroup') === 0) {
    $region_name = str_replace(array(' ','-'), '_', $variables['region']);
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'region__'.$region_name;
  }
}
```

** This function should be there. If not, just place it.*

**In your region--footer.tpl.php file:**

```
/**
 * @file
 * theme implementation to display a region footer
 * variables:
 * - $content: The content for this region, typically blocks.
 * - $classes: String of classes that can be used to style contextually through CSS
 * - $region: The name of the region variable as defined in the theme's .info file.
 * - $classes_array: Array of html class attribute values. It is flattened into a string within the variable $classes.
 * - $is_admin: Flags true when the current user is an administrator.
 * - $is_front: Flags true when presented in the front page.
 * - $logged_in: Flags true when the current user is a logged-in member.
 */
?>

<?php if ($content): ?>
  <div class="your_region_class">

      <?php print $content; ?>

  </div><!-- /.region -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

** read comments*

Comment: Jack, you are right the preprocessor method is missing in template.php. I will come try this out at later time as i have move forward with the 'include'. Thank You

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad I could help.